# Centering labels in pie. Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have the following pie chart: http://jsfiddle.net/wjqrh/76/

```
    new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'f-chart-container',
            type: 'pie',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                shadow: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<span style="color: ' + this.point.color + '; font-weight: bold; font-size: 115%">'
                            + this.point.percentage.toFixed(1)
                            + '%</span>';
                    },
                    distance: 3,
                    connectorWidth: 0,
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: '
                    + this.point.y
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: '',
                data: data,
                size: '73%',
                innerSize: '50%',
                showInLegend: false
            }
        ],
        colors: colors
    });
```

The label of the violet sector is placed somewhere right but I would like to place it exactly in the center, like the third (green) sector's label is displayed.
The same label positioning thing is happening with orange and cyan sectors.

How can I force to place labels in the center of the sector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only what comes to my mind is using translate() function, which allows to move SVG elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/wjqrh/77/

```
chart.series[0].data[5].dataLabel.translate(275,520);
```

Comment: Thank you, but does it mean that I'm not able to apply corrections automatically for other sets of data?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because we caluclate each position separately.